# 開発中のMs Teamsアプリを起動するとconfigurableTabs[0].configurationUrl | String "" does not match regex pattern "^[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp][Ss]?://"

Tags: microsoft-teams

開発中のアプリを起動すると以下のエラーが出るようになってしまいました。

```
configurableTabs[0].configurationUrl | String "" does not match regex pattern "^[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp][Ss]?://".
```

(思い当たる節は、「アプリ機能」>ボット > 「ユーザーがこのコマンドを使用できるようにする範囲を選択してください」にて、「Group Chat」のチェックを付け外ししたくらい？)

開発者ポータルでマニフェストを見ると下記の記載があり、`configurationUrl`部分が空文字になっているのが原因だと思いました。

```js
"configurableTabs": [
    {
        "configurationUrl": "",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
        "scopes": [
            "team"
        ]
    }
],
```

マニフェストから`configurableTabs`を削除したいのですが、どうしたらいいでしょうか？
「アプリの機能」は個人用アプリ(タブ)とボットを指定しいます。